# Parse fixed width, insert into array. How?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse the [Powerball lottery text file](http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt), add each of the 6 columns to their own array and then play around with it a little bit.

Here's an example of the data:

```
Draw Date   WB1 WB2 WB3 WB4 WB5 PB  PP
04/03/2013  35  08  12  01  06  03  
03/30/2013  23  46  11  26  55  27  
03/27/2013  43  48  07  37  52  16  
03/23/2013  29  53  52  17  31  31  
03/20/2013  43  17  14  13  54  15  
03/16/2013  44  53  07  21  03  16  
...
```

Here's what I had in mind:

```
int[] column1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] column2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] column3 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] column4 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] column5 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] column6 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

Just need a little hand with the parsing function. Something like PHP's explode function would be nice.

Comment: `Hey Vini` good luck trying to write something that could guarantee you  winning the `Lotto` Many have Tried, `NONE have Succeeded`

Comment: hehehe. I know.. Just seems that the upcoming numbers can always be found in the last 59 picks for some reason.

Comment: Well perhaps you have about a few million you can waste on trying to do permutations/combinations on that particular analysis good luck ..hey hit me up when you win..LOL

Answer (score 3):

Basic mode of operation: Split into lines, split by separator, work on data. A simple parsing function might be:

```
var cli = new WebClient();
var raw = cli.DownloadString("http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt");
var lines = raw.Split('\n');
var records = from line in lines.Skip(1)
              let parts = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              select new {
                Date = DateTime.Parse(parts[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Numbers = parts.Skip(1).Take(6).Select(x => int.Parse(x))
              };
```

Comment: clever. how do i add each column to its own separate array? your code seems pretty dynamic. having a hard time understanding where the output is and how to push it into the arrays.

Comment: IEnumerable. Have no idea how it works and the more I read about it, the less I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the Split function

```
"text and stuffz".Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like the fixed-width approach instead of splitting (splitting is easier however), you can just use substring functions:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(line.Substring(0, 10), "MM\\/dd\\/yyyy");
string[] nums = new string[6];
nums[0] = line.Substring(12, 2).Trim();
nums[1] = line.Substring(16, 2).Trim();
etc...
```

or

```
string[] nums = new[]
    {
        line.Substring(12, 2).Trim(),
        line.Substring(16, 2).Trim(),
        etc...
    };
```